# Google Workspace: really no free "shared mailbox" like in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: google-workspace, microsoft-teams

I´m searching for a possibility to create a "shared mailbox" in Google Worksspace. My company has A LOT of shared mailboxes like info@example.org, sales@example.org and so on.

In Microsoft Teams, you can create a shared mailbox/email-address and grant access to some users. In this case, there is only an email/mailbox created and NO user. This means, you don´t have to pay a monthly fee for the email/mailbox.

I didn´t find a solution in Google Workspace with the same scenario. In Google Workspace you can create "delegate" an email. But in this case, the email has to belong to some user account, which means you have to pay for this account. You can also set up an email-alias but this means, only one user will get the email which is sent to the alias.

Is there really no chance to create free shared email-addresses in Google Workspace and grant access to just send/receive/archive these emails with multiple different (paid) users? I don´t want to pay a monthly fee for every of my about 30 barely used email-addresses.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance